# uWSGI runs Python 2 with Plugin Python36 -> doesn't find Django in Venv

Tags: django, linux, nginx, deployment, uwsgi

I'm trying to setup a simple Django project with Nginx, uWSGI on my Centos7-Server with this Tutorial:

[How to Serve Django Applications with uWSGI and Nginx on CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-centos-7)

But I've tried to change this project into running Django **2** with Python **3.6**

Everything worked pretty well, till creating **firstsite.ini** file.

```
  1 [uwsgi]
  2 project = firstsite
  3 username = user
  4 base = /home/%(username)
  5 plugins-dir = /usr/lib64/uwsgi/
  6 plugin = python36
  7 virtualenv = %(base)/Env/%(project)
  8 chdir = %(base)/%(project)
  9 home = %(base)/Env/%(project)
 10 module = %(project).wsgi:application
 11 
 12 master = true
 13 processes = 5
 14 
 15 uid = %(username)
 16 socket = /run/uwsgi/%(project).sock
 17 chown-socket = %(username):nginx
 18 chmod-socket = 660
 19 vacuum = true
```

There I got stuck into. While setting up and trying to reach the Django Site I got an Internal Server Error. After checking error-log files and messages, I've implemented *logto* into my .ini file::

```
   21 #Error Logs
   22 logto = %(base)/%(project)/error.log
```

after checking this file it tells me this Error-Message::

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.18 (64bit) on [Wed Aug 14 13:27:24 2019] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36) on 23 July 2019 10:27:56
os: Linux-3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 18 16:35:19 UTC 2019
nodename: ip-172-31-34-37.eu-central-1.compute.internal
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /etc/uwsgi/sites
detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi
chdir() to /home/user/firstsite
your processes number limit is 3775
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /run/uwsgi/firstsite.sock fd 3
setuid() to 1001
Python version: 2.7.5 (default, Jun 20 2019, 20:27:34)  [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]
Set PythonHome to /home/user/Env/firstsite
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x234f0e0
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 437520 bytes (427 KB) for 5 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./firstsite/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 21976)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 21978, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 21979, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 21980, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 21981, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 5 (pid: 21982, cores: 1)
```

If I manually try to get this django project runing with the same Env, there is no problem. So  I thought that it could be because of the fact that uwsgi is running Python 2.7.5 instead of Python 3.6.

I also checked the plugin python with *uwsgi --plugin python36 -s:0*

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.18 (64bit) on [Thu Aug 15 04:16:19 2019] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36) on 14 August 2019 14:16:35
os: Linux-3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 18 16:35:19 UTC 2019
nodename: ip-172-31-34-37.eu-central-1.compute.internal
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /usr/lib64/uwsgi
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 3775
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address :37796 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
Python version: 3.6.8 (default, Apr 25 2019, 21:02:35)  [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x17756c0
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 72920 bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 6476, cores: 1)
```

So it looks to me, that I've created my 36-plugin the right way.
Would be really grateful if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

this is where the real problem is it can't find django
are you sure that django is installed in that environment you mentioned?
i mean "Env"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./firstsite/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
```

in that link you mentioned i couldn't find

```
virtualenv = %(base)/Env/%(project)
```

try changing it to

```
virtualenv = %(base)/Env
```

if that didnt solve your problem please specify django, python versions you are using plus your project structure

Comment: Thx for your answer! I need python 3 to run django 2, but it seems that uwsgi runs python 2.7.5

Comment: Unfortunately it did not. So, I added some more details about my problem and updatet my question.